# Laravel: how to get pivot data for a specific record

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

From the documentation I see `->pivot->` is used like so

```
@foreach($program->attendees as $attendee)
        {{$attendee->pivot->paid;}}
@endforeach
```

I want to find the pivot data for one specific `$attendee` like so...

```
$program->attendees->find($attendee)->pivot->paid;
```

but I get error: *Trying to get property of non-object*

I don't know what is wrong because the `@foreach` version works. If I run
  `{{$program->attendees->find($attendee)}}`

I get

```
{"id":"1","created_at":"2015-03-02 21:35:30","updated_at":"2015-03-02 21:35:30","first_name":"Chris","last_name":"Griffin","birthday":"2010-10-08","media_release":"1","food_allergies":"peanuts","special_care":"","user_id":"2","pivot":{"scheduled_program_id":"1","attendee_id":"1","paid":"0"}} 0
```

Which looks like the pivot data is there...

Comment: Strange... Your code actually looks correct to me. Does `$program->attendees->find($attendee)->pivot` work?

Comment: I get the error stated above. `{{$program->attendees->find($attendee)}}` works and I get the result as stated above. I think maybe that is the key to the answer?

Comment: Do you do this inside a loop? (`{{$program->attendees->find($attendee)}}`)

Comment: yes I am filling out a list of programs for the specific attendee. It is inside a loop  `@foreach($programs as $program)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're doing it inside a loop and not every program actually has an attendee with that id.

This should fix it:

```
@foreach($programs as $program)
    @if($a = $program->attendees->find($attendee))
        {{ $a->pivot->paid }}
    @endif
@endforeach
```

By the way I noticed that by the `0` at the end of your output. That's probably the second program that doesn't have an attendee with this id.

Comment: Wow you are so sharp! So glad you are here giving help! <3

Answer (score 1):

see your find method within the following line:

```
$program->attendees->find($attendee)->pivot->paid;
```

It needs the id value to query your model and then get the pivot. Did you try using the `$attendee->id` value?

```
$program->attendees->find($attendee->id)->pivot->paid;
```

Comment: Yes, I tried `$program->attendees->find($attendee->id)->pivot->paid;` It has the exact same result for both the error and the printout from `{{$program->attendees->find($attendee)}}`

Answer (score 0):

When you define your relationship you should also apply `withPivot()` method like:

```
public function attendees(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Attendee')->withPivot('paid', 'other_pivot_column');
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I have `$this->belongsToMany('ScheduledProgram', 'prog_bookings')->withPivot('paid');` in my model already.
As I said in my original question the`@foreach` version works for me. I don't think it would work if I didn't do that.